# Trying to calculate how long between sounds picked up via mic

Tags: javascript, timer, p5.js

I am trying to calculate the amount of time between the first sounds the mic hears and the second sound the mic hears.

```
var mic;
var vol;
var myTimer = 0;
var myState = 0;
var count = 0;
var waitingForVolumeIncrease = false;
var crackDetected = false;
var m
var micSensitivity = 3;
var startTime, endTime;
var millisec;
var endMilliSec, startMilliSec;


function start() {
  startTime = new Date();
  startMilliSec = startTime.getMilliseconds();

  text(startMilliSec, 60, 375);
}

function end() {
  endTime = new Date();
  endMilliSec = endTime.getMilliseconds();

  text(endMilliSec, 60, 375);
}

function findDiff() {
  text(endMilliSec, 100, 380);
  text(startMilliSec, 140, 385);

  var timeDiff = endMilliSec - startMilliSec; //in ms

  text(timeDiff, 60, 100);
}



function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
}

function draw() {
  background('pink');

  vol = mic.getLevel(); // level is between 0 and 1
  vol = vol * 100;

  switch(myState) {

    case 0:
      if ((vol > micSensitivity)&&(waitingForVolumeIncrease==false)) {
        start();
        waitingForVolumeIncrease = true;
        myState = 1;
      }
    break;

    case 1:
      if ((vol > micSensitivity)&&(waitingForVolumeIncrease==true)) {
        end();
        waitingForVolumeIncrease = false
        myState = 0;
      }
    break;

  }

  findDiff();

  text(waitingForVolumeIncrease, 60, 325)

  textSize(18);
  text("My volume is " + vol, 40, 550);
}
```

I want to start counting milliseconds in case 0 then count milliseconds in case 1 then find the difference. however, when I run this code I get either 17 or 16 milliseconds every time regardless of how long between the two sounds. Where am I going wrong with my code?

My goal is to listen for each time the front then back wheels on a skateboard hit a crack in the sidewalk so I can calculate the time in millisecond between each crack and then convert it to how fast you are traveling in MPH

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
[getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) instead of using [getMilliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds).

The call to getMilliseconds only gets you the milliseconds relative to the last full second.

```js
var startTime = new Date();
console.log("getMilliseconds: " + startTime.getMilliseconds());
console.log("getTime: " + startTime.getTime());
startTime.setMilliseconds(123);
console.log("getMilliseconds: " + startTime.getMilliseconds());
console.log("getTime: " + startTime.getTime());
```